# body acceleration in contact between two bodies

Tags: contact

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey,

I am trying to simulate a wheel(cylinder) on a surface (ground_plane). I launch the gazebo with sdf file which contains both models and give it a 3 seconds to get rest with parameters Kp =380 and Kd=10. I can see the spring rest when I look at the output of position and velocities commands of z axis (GetWorldCoGPose() and GetWorldCoGLinearVel() gazebo API commands), but when I use GetWorldLinearAccel() command I get acceleration z value as zero although the wheel is moving.
Sombody knows why? maybe the GetWorldLinearAccel() is not the right command?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7752/body-acceleration-in-contact-between-two-bodies/) by [shpower](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/928/shpower/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

`Link::GetWorldLinearAccel` was [broken for quite a while](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/243), though it has recently been fixed if you build from source. It will be fixed in a new release of gazebo in the next month or so.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0